# Facebook Class not found in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I try Facebook login tutorials and I got

> Class 'Faebook' not found error

. I don't know what I was wrong there

I follow [this link](http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-facebook-login-into-laravel-application/). I already add facebook.php to my config

here's my routes.php

```
Route::get('login/fb', function() {
    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $params = array( 'redirect_uri' => url('/login/fb/callback'), 'scope' => 'email', );
    return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl($params)); 
});
```

Comment: please post relevant code e.g. `Facebook` class and where is it defined in directory structure.

Comment: Did you install the `facebook/php-sdk` package as described? Did you try a `composer dump-autoload` after installing the package?

Comment: Have you actually imported the class?